# Windows 8.1 single language получится изменить язык интерфейса без переустановки?

Tags: windows

Говорят есть обходные пути, но про ще забить

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в настройки - язык и дата - в панели слева выберете язык.

В данном меню перетащите нужный вам язык на самый верх.

[image: В данном меню перетащите нужный вам язык на самый верх.]

Перезагрузите ПК.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В SL нет такой возможности

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего изменить его на глобальном уровне получится только установкой языкового пакета и выбор его в панели управления.

Скачать можно отсюда: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-windows-a5094319-a92d-18de-5b53-1cfc697cfca8#WindowsVersion=Windows_8.1

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Русский предлагает скачивать через панель управления